# How to call Sling Model Method with input parameter AEM

Tags: aem, sightly, sling-models

I am having a scenario in which i want to call a sling model with input parameter.
For  this i have a code like this

```
<div data-sly-use.model3="${'com.bhf.aem.sling.models.Test' @ colour='red'}">
</div>
```

But I want to call a method in sling model twice with two different parameters .Is it possible with sling models?

Any Help!!!

Answer (score 3):

From AEM 6.3 there is a new HTL feature that allows to do this.

In the data-sly-include and data-sly-resource you can now pass
 requestAttributes in order to use them in the receiving HTL-script.
 This allows you to properly pass-in parameters into scripts or
 components.

```
<sly data-sly-use.settings="com.adobe.examples.htl.core.hashmap.Settings" 
        data-sly-include="${ 'productdetails.html' @ requestAttributes=settings.settings}"/>
```

Java-code of the Settings class, the Map is used to pass in the
 requestAttributes:

```
public class Settings extends WCMUsePojo {

  // used to pass is requestAttributes to data-sly-resource
  public Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  @Override
  public void activate() throws Exception {
    settings.put("layout", "flex");
  }
}
```

For example, via a Sling-Model, you can consume the value of the specified requestAttributes. In this example, layout is injected via the Map from the Use-class:

```
@Model(adaptables=SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class ProductSettings {

  @Inject @Optional @Default(values="empty")
  public String layout;
}
```

Comment: This is actually another way to pass parameters *during initialization*, not when calling a method.

Answer (score 1):

By design of the HTL/Sightly language, sending parameters is only possible for `data-sly-use` (use objects initialization)  and `data-sly-call` (template calls). The reason for this is to separate business logic from the view.

As mentioned by @tomasz-szymulewski, since https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5812, there is support for passing request attributes on resource/script inclusion in the Sling/AEM implementation.